# FIR Filter delay calculation for cascaded filters

Tags: filter, dsp, simulink, fir

I have created a simulink model which had two filters implemented with an FIR block cascaded in series.[image]
The first filter in my case is a moving average filter and the second one a Gaussian filter(being a special case of an FIR filter), which would obviously generate a delay ,Now my confusion is for the amount of delay it will produce.  For symmetric coefficients for a single FIR  filter it is (number of co-effcients)/2 but for a cascaded form would it be the (number of coeffcients of filter1 + number of coeffcients of filter2) /2 or (number of coeffcients)/2 +1 as there is one sample delay between both the filters assuming that the number of coefficients of both the filters are the same

Comment: Easy enough to test your understanding.

Comment: @BrianDrummond can u elaborate please

Comment: Delay your input signal by the hypothesised delay, and compare with (or subtract from) the output.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks for your input , I will try that but I also want to understand the reason behind it if its either of those